# Little endian and overwriting memory location

Tags: c, memory, undefined-behavior, endianness

First of all I’ll make it clear that I know this piece of code is UB. Still I am not sure how this works.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int x[] = {1, 2, 3};
char s[] = "hello";

int main()
{
    puts(s);
    x[3] = ('e' << 16) + ('y' << 8) + 'b';
    puts(s);
}
```

So this prints Hello and bye. Certainly it is UB but I would like to know what is happening here.
I thought I understood how little endian and big endian worked but obviously that’s not the case since I’ve been looking at this for the past 30 minutes and still don’t get what’s going on.

I would REALLY appreciate a diagram if possible…

My understanding:

- ‘x’ and ‘s’ are laid out seauentially in memory with this output.
- overwriting x[3] overwrites s.

I don’t get:

- how and why ‘bye’ is printed. What is happening to the memory. Let’s assume it’s not UB…
- How and why a null terminator is inserted after ‘e’ in ‘bye’.
- what endianness has to do with all of this.

Thanks.

Comment: Ignoring UB, your understanding is correct. Draw your array (and stack) on paper, it will soon become clear. It feels like you know the answer and just want someone to tell you  that you are right. If that's not true, please edit your question to focus on the bit you're confused about.

Comment: gcc -O3 prints "hello" "hello" though. That's the thing with UB, it's not easy to reproduce. I can reproduce it with clang -O3.

Answer (score 5):

This expression:

```
('e' << 16) + ('y' << 8) + 'b'
```

has type `int` with a value (assuming ASCII) in hex of `0x00657962`.  You then store it using an lvalue of type `int`.  Assuming `int` is 32 bits and little endian byte ordering, it is represented with the above bytes reversed, i.e. `0x62 0x79 0x65 0x00`.  When those bytes are interpreted as a string, you have the characters `bye` followed by a null terminating byte, which reflects what is printed.

Comment: - why is the null character added in this case? Is it mandated here?

Comment: Also: assuming LE, does this mean that puts reads the first char from the highest memory address?

Comment: The value you wrote, again assuming a 4-byte `int`, contains 3 non-zero bytes and 1 zero byte, with the zero byte being the most signifigant.  And because that value was stored in little endian format, the byte with value 0 ends up after the non-zero bytes.

Comment: `puts`, like all functions that work with strings, works with a single byte at a time, where each byte in the array has an increasing address.

Answer (score 4):

Without padding and assuming that `x` and `s` are adjacent in memory, `x[3]` is the address of the *fourth* element of a three-element array, and with the above assumptions, the memory looks like this

```
|x[0]|x[1]|x[2]|s[0]|s[1]|s[1]|s[3]|......
            or |       x[3]        | <- doesn't really exist, UB to write to it
```

That also assumes `int` values are 4 bytes.  And note the sizes of elements of `x` less than 3 are not to scale.

In little-endian format, the code

```
x[3] = ('e' << 16) + ('y' << 8) + 'b';
```

sets the bytes of x[3] to

```
| 'b' | 'y' | 'e' | 0  |
```

or, lined up again:

```
|x[0]|x[1]|x[2]|s[0]|s[1]|s[1]|s[3]|...
               | 'b'| 'y'| 'e'| 0  |
```